# AUCTeX does not autocomplete environment commands of packages loaded in TeX-master

Tags: emacs, auctex, auto-completion, multiple-files

I am encountering a similar problem to [this very old question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/getting-auctex-and-amsmath-to-work-with-multiple-files), in that AUCTeX is not autocompleting commands outside the TeX-master file.

I have the following files:

`main.tex`:

```tex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: latexmk: { clean: partial }
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
What follows are some equations.
\input{sections/equations}

\end{document}
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

and a subordinate file

`sections/equations.tex`

```tex
\section{Some equations}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "../main"
%%% End:
```

The problem is that while loading the `amsmath` package in `main.tex`, the corresponding environments (e.g. `\align`) are *only* autocompletable in `main.tex`, and not in `sections/equations.tex`. As it appears that AUXTeX should support this behavior out-of-the-box (see the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Multifile.html)), what am I missing?

#### Emacs `config.org`

As I think the error might originate from my Emacs configuration, the relevant Emacs configuration for AUXTeX is:

```lisp
(use-package tex
    :ensure auctex
    :config
    (setq-default TeX-master nil)
    (setq TeX-auto-save t
          TeX-parse-self t)
    (setq font-latex-fontify-sectioning 'color)  ;; Disable fontification, e.g. \section
    (setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
    (setq reftex-bibliography-commands '("bibliography" "nobibliography" "addbibresource"))
    ;; Add Zathura as default (see below)
    (add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-selection '(output-pdf "Zathura"))
    ;; Add hooks
    :hook ((LaTeX-mode . turn-on-reftex)              ;; Turn on RefTeX
           (LaTeX-mode . eglot-ensure)                ;; Turn on eglot (LSP)
           (LaTeX-mode . TeX-source-correlate-mode)   ;; Correlated PDF and tex file       
           (TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions . TeX-revert-document-buffer)))
```

Comment: With your setup above, do you get a file `./auto/main.el` under the directory where you `main.tex` resides when you save `main.tex`?  It should look like this: `(TeX-add-style-hook "main" (lambda () (TeX-run-style-hooks "latex2e" "sections/equations" "report" "rep10" "amsmath")) :latex)`

Comment: Yes I do, the contents are more verbose that your example, but does include the part that you mention. I also want to add that environment completion using `C-c C-e` does work, the autocompletion simply does not trigger when inserting `\align` (which does trigger completing the align environment in `main.tex`).

Comment: So you expect you insert `\align` in the buffer and you get `\begin{align}...\end{align}` completion?  Where have you read about this feature of AUCTeX?  Or maybe this is a feature of the LSP-Server you're using?

Comment: This is indeed what I expect, but now that you mention it this might actually be the LSP server, and not AUCTeX.